# JSF page loading data before constructor

Tags: jsf-2, managed-bean

I made a NotificationHandler class, this class contains a static List.
To allow access to this list I made a SessionScopped bean with a getter returning this list.

**My problem is the following :**

I'm on page A, I put a notification in the list, page A is regenerated, the notification is being displayed.

Then I click on a link in page A sending me to page B.

In page B there is a constructor wich destroy the list.
However the JSF page display the notification BEFORE calling the constructor.

I end up on page B with a notification for page A

Notification handler:

```
package com.cog.util;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class NotificationHandler {

private static List<Notification2> listeDeNotification = new ArrayList<Notification2>();

public static void flushNotification(){
    listeDeNotification.clear();
}

public static void raiseNotification(NotificationColor color, String code){
    listeDeNotification.add(new Notification2(color.toString(), code));
}

public static void raiseNotification(NotificationColor color, String code, String additionalMessage){
    listeDeNotification.add(new Notification2(color.toString(), code, additionalMessage));
}

public static void addAdditionalMessage(String code, String additionalMessage){
    for(Notification2 n : listeDeNotification){
        if (n.getCode().equals(code)){
            n.setAdditionalMessage(additionalMessage);
        }
    }
}

public static Integer getNotificationNumber(){
    return listeDeNotification.size();
}

public static List<Notification2> getListeDeNotification(){
    return listeDeNotification;
}
```

}

notificationPrinter.xhtml

```
<composite:interface>
    <composite:attribute name="liste" />
    <composite:attribute name="locale" />
</composite:interface>

<composite:implementation>
    <ui:repeat value="#{cc.attrs.liste}" varStatus="status" var="l">
        <h:panelGrid width="100%" columns="1">
            <div id="alert" class="alert #{l.color}">
                <button class="close" data-dismiss="alert" type="button">×</button>
                <span class="rt">#{cc.attrs.locale[l.code]} #{l.additionalMessage}</span>
            </div>
        </h:panelGrid>
    </ui:repeat>
</composite:implementation>
```

AccessorBean

```
package com.cog.web.beans.util;

import java.util.List;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import com.cog.util.Notification2;
import com.cog.util.NotificationHandler;


@ManagedBean(name = "notificationAccessor")
@SessionScoped
public class NotificationAccessorBean {

    public List<Notification2> getNotificationList(){
        return NotificationHandler.getListeDeNotification();
    }

}
```

and this is what I put in jsf

problem is I want to flush the notification list betwen some pages only.

Comment: not sure , but sounds like you should use `@ManagedProperty` to access one bean from another , and in that way you will be able to access and flush the notification before navigation...

Comment: Not sure if I can do that because there is nothing beside a getter in the NotificationAccessorBean, should I put the content of NotificationHandler in the bean?

Comment: when you navigate between pages you referring to any method in your `action` attribute ? if so, its probably implemented in some bean , so in that bean create a `@ManagedProperty` of NotificationHandler and flush the notifications (something like that)

Comment: No, i'm using regular link : <a class="tabProduit" href="#{facesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath}/vues/produit/rechercherGamme.xhtml">#{msg.RechercherUneGamme}</a>.

So I cannot call any method to flush.

Comment: Since you are using JSF you can use its advantages (`h:commandLink for example`) , you can also might use the `preRenderView` try placing it in your page and use its listener to flush the list http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-prerenderviewevent-example/

Comment: Unfortunatly the project already has a lot of pages with a lot of link, futhermore it would render code complexity to high for the next develloper team, that's why I choose not to replace each link by h:commandlink with a method called.

however your "<f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{notificationAccessor.flush}"/>" works perfectly =D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using JSF you can use its advantages (`h:commandLink for example`) , you can also might use the `preRenderView` try placing it in your page and use its `listener` to flush the list

take a look at the following explanation/example [JSF 2 PreRenderViewEvent example](http://mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-prerenderviewevent-example)

Comment: yes, using preRenderView work, thanks =D
However know that I found why this is happening : richfaces, when their is no richfaces on the page the constructor is being called BEFORE the notification drawing process.

Comment: You welcome, although I'm not sure how the presence of richfaces changes the order of the constructor call..